# xcode deleting SQL-Database from Device

Tags: xcode

im working with xcode 4.5 and ios simulator 6.0 and i want to delete the database im working with but i dont know how. i want to set up the database completly new.

i read that it is possible just to delete the file under Macintosh/Library/Application Support/iOS Simulator. But this folder doesnt exists on my mac.

So how can i delete my database?

```
- (void)createOrOpenDB {
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"WorkoutPlans.db"];

    char *error;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString]) {
        const char *dbPath = [dbPathString UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &workoutPlansDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
            const char *sql_cr_wp = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORKOUTPLANS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , NAME TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE , DESCRIPTION TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE)";
            const char *sql_cr_en = "CREATE TABLE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENTITY (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , NAME TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE , DESCRIPTION TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE )";
            const char *sql_cr_ex = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EXERCISE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , NAME TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE , DESCRIPTION TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE , REPS TEXT NOT NULL , WEIGHT TEXT NOT NULL)";
            const char *sql_cr_plen = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WPEN (PLANID, ENID, FOREIGN KEY(PLANID) REFERENCES WORKOUTPLANS(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(ENID) REFERENCES ENTITY(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)";
            const char *sql_cr_enex = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENEX (ENTITYID, EXERCISEID, FOREIGN KEY(ENTITYID) REFERENCES ENTITY(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(EXERCISEID) REFERENCES EXERCISE(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)";

            sqlite3_exec(workoutPlansDB, sql_cr_wp, NULL, NULL, &error);
            sqlite3_exec(workoutPlansDB, sql_cr_ex, NULL, NULL, &error);
            sqlite3_exec(workoutPlansDB, sql_cr_en, NULL, NULL, &error);
            sqlite3_exec(workoutPlansDB, sql_cr_plen, NULL, NULL, &error);
            sqlite3_exec(workoutPlansDB, sql_cr_enex, NULL, NULL, &error);
            sqlite3_close(workoutPlansDB);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call a delete method in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

```
if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString]) {
   [fileManager removeItemAtPath:dbPathString error:&error];
}
```